# How would I generate an HTML form based on table data from two different tables using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I am trying to write a PHP script that will create an HTML form using the “field_definitions” table as a source for input fields and set the default values of each field based on previously stored results from the “user_data” table. (based on the currently logged in user… I have an auth system setup and running using session variables.)

My tables are like so...

```
users TABLE
user_id user_email       user_firstname user_lastname user_password
1       johndoe@mail.com John           Doe           password

field_definitions TABLE
field_id field_type field_length field_name field_desc                   field_section
1        text       40           color      What is your favorite color? 1

user_data TABLE
response_id user_id field_id user_response
1           1       1        Blue
```

I’ve created a block of code that returns the rows from my “field_definitions” table and stores them in an array. I’m able to use a foreach loop to generate the form based on each row in the array, but I can’t figure out how to pull-in the second set of information from the other table for the default values.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(sqlhost, sqluser, sqlsecret, sqldb);

$field_definitions_query = "SELECT * FROM field_definitions WHERE field_section = '1'";

$field_definitions_data = mysqli_query($dbc, $field_definitions_query);

$field_definitions = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($field_definitions_data)) {
  array_push($field_definitions, $row);
}
echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">';

foreach ($field_definitions as $row) {
 echo '<label for="' . $row[field_name] . '">' . $row[field_desc] . ':</label>';
 echo '<input type="' . $row[field_type] . '" id="' . $row[field_name] . '" name="' . $row[field_name]. '" value="temp" /><br />';
}

echo '<input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" /></form>';
```

Do I need to create a second array of the other table data, then merge the two in someway?

Is my general approach feasible, or is there a better way?

I am a beginner in PHP and programming in general and would rather not try and conquer any of the frameworks out there; I’m trying to pull this off with my own code for the sake of learning.

Comment: You should really remove these images that expose your hostname publically! You can put your sql as text in your post

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: You want to learn about JOIN. Join commands are a fundamental part of what SQL does (and of what separates it from storing all your data in a spreadsheet). Learn about JOINs and you will level up twice, and unlock a large portion of SQL's true power! [Here](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php) is one of many quick tutorials that can get you started. protip: some people like to introduce JOIN by talking about inner joins and outer joins and left vs. right vs. straight, but as a beginner, you will almost always be using inner joins, so don't let the other stuff confuse you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using SQL JOIN construction. In case of MySQL it would be something like this:
`select t1.*, t2.user_response from field_definitions t1 left join user_data t2 using (field_id) where t2.user_id = %USER_ID% or t2.user_id is null`. Then you can fetch data row-by-row to a single array/hash/whatever. See your SQL manual for more details on JOINs.

In short. We are joining tables `t1` and `t2` by field `x`. N is NULL (non-existent) record. `Ljn` is LEFT JOIN, `Rjn` is RIGHT JOIN, `Ijn` is INNER JOIN (INNER keyword is frequently ommited) and `Fjn` is FULL JOIN

`t1.x: 1 2 3 4 5 N N`

`t2.x: N N N 4 5 6 7`

`Ljn : ^_______^----`

`Rjn : -----^______^`

`Ijn : -----^__^----`

`Fjn : ^___________^`

You can check if record is non-existing one by `t1.x IS NULL` or `t1.x IS NOT NULL` in where clause.

Hope it will help.

Comment: what is the t1 & t2? I'm new to SQL as well. I'm using MySQL.

Comment: It's just an aliases for tables field_definitions and user_data tables;

Comment: so would it be field_definitions AS t1, or is that implied?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. You can skip keyword AS actually.

Comment: one more question... if they have never filled the form out before and therefore don't have any rows in the user_data table, will I still get results to build the form?

Comment: @Corey Yes, you will. That's why you use LEFT JOIN and not INNER JOIN. You really should read something about joins, it will help you alot.

Comment: I've been searching and reading about "join" and "where" but I haven't been able to get the "where" to only apply to the table on the right of join. when i use "select field_definitions.*, user_data.user_response from field_definitions left join user_data using (field_id) where user_data.user_id = 1" i only get one result even though i have two rows in field_definitions

Comment: `select t1.*, t2.user_response from field_definitions t1 left join user_data t2 using (field_id) where t2.user_id = %USER_ID% or t2.user_id is null`

Comment: thanks so much !!!, this works like a champ, i think i will buy a MySQL book. Have any suggestions?

Comment: Hey, that's a really nice illustration of different join types. Very compact and mnemonically helpful. Also cheerful! Did you just invent it, or is the concept taken from elsewhere?

Comment: @octern Well, thats how I understand it. And I guess that's exactly what SQL inventors meant by LEFT, RIGHT and so on :) The only mnemonic trick is to place t1 to the left side.

Comment: Sure, I just like the way your diagram juxtaposes all the different result sets. Other people who illustrate joins tend to use venn diagrams, which are much bulkier. They make it easier to see what's being taken from which table, but harder to see how the result sets differ from one another.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this. I posted a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883156/how-can-i-make-a-where-clause-only-apply-to-the-right-table-in-a-left-join